# cross browser functionality for horizontal scroll for a table

Tags: html, css

I am using Elementor page builder.  I mention this because it allows css to be placed in the widget itself.

I have two versions of a div table, one for PC and Tablet and another for Mobile only.  They are co-existing on the same page but have display options set in each section.

Two days ago I gave the mobile version an extra class name of "scroll-table" and applied this css snippet to it;

```
table.scroll-table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The table scrolled horizontally quite nicely on Firefox mobile browser and well enough on Chrome mobile browser (client viewed on this browser).  It was a very long day so I called it quits.

Yesterday I added some more css to place a button where the signup links were (final right hand column).   I did this by adding the class name "button" to the links, "btn" seemed to be pre-existing because it immediately shrunk the text.  Then I added this css snippet in both widgets (Mobile and PC).

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #F39C25;
  color: #fff;
}
```

The result was that the buttons appeared, and correctly, however it stopped horizontal scrolling on the Firefox mobile browser, while the Chrome mobile browser scrolls the whole page horizontally.  This behavior on Chrome mobile is acceptable to the client but I am not thrilled with it.  The day before, when it was working on Firefox mobile it scrolled as a container complete with a scroll-bar underneath.  Being tired (and a little under the weather) I assumed this is what the client was seeing as well.

Adding !important to the  `overflow-x: auto;` has no effect so I removed it again.

I have no problem adding css to the style.css if that would help, and have a Child theme installed.  However, in the Elementor FB group there has been much ado about "You don't need a child theme." and thought in this case the widgets would be a more appropriate place to place it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to state the question more clearly. What is it that you want to solve?

Comment: Would like to return the horizontal scroll to functional.  Not sure why the css for the buttons is interfering with the scroll css.  Doesn't seem like it should.  Maybe In am missing something?